# Copy files to local drive that requires different credentials

Tags: vb.net, command-line, permissions

I've seen a lot of answers on copying files that use code to set a network share, with credentials, to copy to somewhere else. However I need a solution that will allow a user to copy from a network share they already have access for, to a local drive they don't have access to.

We run RDS servers and have locked down direct access to the local C:/ drive on the servers. We have been given a 3rd party program that needs to read data files that must be stored in a fixed path on the C:/ drive. These data files are updated once a month. Our users have read access but we do not want to give them direct write access to the root C:/ drive.

I need to write a piece of vb.net, or command line code in .bat file that will copy files to the Local C:/ whilst providing the details of a service account to provide the access.

As mentioned I've seen a lot about setting up a mapping to shared folder and passing creds, however we don't want to set the C:/ as mapped shared drive in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the user having access to the C Drive in general, is there any particular reason the permissions on the particular subfolder the files are going to can't have overriding permissions to allow writing to just that folder?

If that will not work, first thought that comes to mind is having a helper program that can be ran under a different user that does have that access. Set up an intermediate folder the user can write to, the program that they can launch drops the files into a folder they have access to. Helper program watches for files in the intermediate folder, moves them to where they need to be.

Set up would need to include adding a user that does have access to both locations, and then adding to task manager to launch the helper program under that other user at login.